# Determining if an XDocument File Exists

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

I am using LINQ and I was wondering what is the best way to create an XDocument and then check to make sure that the XDocument actually exists, much like File.Exists?

```
String fileLoc = "path/to/file";
XDocument doc = new XDocument(fileLoc);
//Now I want to check to see if this file exists
```

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you check File.Exists first?

Comment: Well I thought of that but there is no way to create an XDocument from a File as far as I'm aware...If there is please let me know :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

An XML file is still a file; just use `File.Exists`.

Just a cautionary note, though: Don't bother trying to check `File.Exists` immediately before loading the document.  There is no way to guarantee that the file will still be there when you try to open it.  Writing this code:

```
if (File.Exists(fileName))
{
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(fileName);
    // etc.
}
```

...is a race condition and always wrong.  Instead, just try loading the document and catch the exception.

```
try
{
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(fileName);
    // Process the file
}
catch (FileNotFoundException)
{
    // File does not exist - handle the error
}
```

Comment: Don't understand why it is a race condition. Please can you elaborate?